# INSERT INTO fails if inserting a variable with the value of Null

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

The SQL INSERT INTO will fail if the variable I am inserting has the value of Null.

The variable costLab is Variant data type. The non-Null value would be Decimal.

```
db.Execute ("INSERT INTO budget 
(wbsid, category, capture_date, budget_date, budget_type, month_value) " & _
"VALUES ('" & wbsid & "', 'Labor', #" & importDate & "#, 
#" & monthDate & "#, 'Forecast', " & costLab & ");")
```

I want to insert Null if the code that sets costLab returns Null. But if a value is returned I want to insert that value. Obviously I could write an If statement that checks for null then insert "Null" directly but I wanted to know if there was a way without the If statement to insert Nulls via a variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `Nz()` when you build the `INSERT` statement.  It's similar to the `IIf()` approach, but is slightly more concise.

```vb
Dim strInsert As String
strInsert = "INSERT INTO budget (wbsid, category, capture_date, budget_date, budget_type, month_value) " & _
        "VALUES ('" & wbsid & "', 'Labor', #" & importDate & "#, #" & monthDate & "#, 'Forecast', " & Nz(costLab, 'Null') & ");"
Debug.Print strInsert ' <- examine the finshed statement in Immediate window
db.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError
```

`Debug.Print` gives you an opportunity to examine the finished statement you give to the db engine to execute.  In case of trouble, you can go to the Immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+g) to view the statement text.  You can also copy that text and paste it into SQL View of a new query for testing.

Comment: Thanks Hans for the quick response. I am still wondering why exactly it is failing in the first place. For example an insert using a SELECT based on a table with a field value of null has no issues whatsoever.

Comment: Examine the output from `Debug.Print`.  My guess is when `costLab` is Null, the last part of the statement built from your original code  will be this ...  `'Forecast', );`

Comment: With the code I suggested, the last part of the statement will end up as this when `costLab` is Null ... `'Forecast', Null);`

Comment: Hans you are correct, the root of my error is that I am creating a string. Therefore a variable with the value of Null will not automatically concatenate the string "Null". Thanks again for helping me work through this one.

Answer (score 1):

Just literally insert "null" when `costLab` is Null.

So, when you concatenate the SQL string, instead of the variable `costLab`, you just insert this:

```
IIf(IsNull(costLab), "null", costlab)
```

The complete query:

```
db.Execute ("INSERT INTO budget (wbsid, category, capture_date, budget_date, budget_type, month_value) " & _
    "VALUES ('" & wbsid & "', 'Labor', #" & importDate & "#, #" & monthDate & "#, 'Forecast', " & IIf(IsNull(costLab), "null", costlab) & ");")
```

---

I know...technically, this **is** an `If` statement (`IIf` is just a short form of `If...Then...Else`), but it's the shortest form that I can think of.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Christian. This is a valid workaround and I understand that, what I do not understand is why I cannot insert the value null simply using the variable. Why does it fail?